# WayBack Machine stopped archiving my site, is there something wrong with my robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/linksku.com

The last time that my site was archived was during July of last year. A few weeks ago I realized that my robots.txt file had an error and I fixed it. However, my site still isn't being crawled. What's wrong?

My robots.txt file is here: http://linksku.com/robots.txt

Comment: You can always tell them to do an archive manually by submitting your page to web.archive.org

Answer (score 0):

The Wayback Machine results can be delayed significantly-- sometimes by six months or more.

Comment: Alexa crawls do appear in the Wayback with a 6th month delay, but that's only a small fraction of our current crawling. In 2012 it was a bigger percentage.

Answer (score -1):

That link is for their old service. The new beta service does archive your website:

http://web-beta.archive.org/web/*/http://linksku.com